# How can i create symbolic link for directory

Tags: linux, symlink, ln

I am trying to create symbolic link as below

```
ln -s /home/scripts/logs  /home/log
```

The directory /home/log is already existing ,which cant be deleted. When i do this it creates the symbolic link as /home/log/logs .I know that if the target is a directory and it already exists `ln -s` will create a sub folder of source inside target directory. But i just want the contents of my source directory (/home/scripts/logs/"test_contents")  to be in target(/home/log/"test_contents"). Do we gave any solution for this 
Note: i cant remove /home/logs which contains logs of other applications

Comment: Do it the other way around? Delete `/home/scripts/logs` and make it a link to `/home/log`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have your `ln -s` command backwards.  The first operand is where you want the link to point, and the second is what you want to call the symbolic link itself.

You can remember the order of the operands with the command `ln -s this here` and read it as "Take *this* and create a symbolic link for it *here*" (just like `mv this here` is "Take *this* and move it *here*", etc.)

The command

```
ln -s /home/logs /home/scripts/logs
```

would create the symbolic link `/home/scripts/logs` pointing to `/home/logs` (assuming `/home/scripts/logs` is not already existing).

In real life, you probably aren't working with directories *directly* beneath `/home` though, so it's likely that you actually want

```
ln -s "$HOME/logs" "$HOME/scripts/logs"
```

... or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to symlink the **files** in your directory, not the directory itself. Then you probably want this:

```
ln -s /home/scripts/logs/*  /home/log/
```

Comment: That'd work for all files *currently* in `/home/scripts/logs/` but not any that are created later. I'm not sure that's what he wants.

Comment: @Petr Tesařík  i need to create symlink for the directory so all the files created later will be present in /home/log

Comment: @xaglez Hm, so, what should happen to the original content of your target directory? Do you expect some magic that *merges* the content of the original directory with the directory you're linking?